# How to get "real" value from input[type=number]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

If I have `input[type=number]`, Chrome allows me to type not just numbers, but also characters like `-` (minus sign) - for negative numbers. And it seems you can actually type multiple of those - minus signs and dots, e.g.: `".....---888"`. And when that happens, in `on-change` event, property of `event.target.value` would be an empty string (because it's not a valid number). But I would like validation message to appear, telling user has to type an actual number.

So the question is: How do I read the actual value, the one that's being displayed in the input field, because it seems, sometimes it's not the same as `event.target.value`

*I don't know if this matters - this is in a React app*

Comment: you don't, unfortunately. You can however read the validationMessage property to see if it's currently invalid. or read the valueAsNumber property to see if it's NaN.

Comment: Could you not just use a regex to remove all of the extra characters, and just extract the digits?

Comment: @ObsidianAge well, no, because you can't *get* the value if it isn't valid (hence this question)

Comment: @KevinB `valueAsNumber` I think is my best option. Thanks!

Comment: "You can't get the value if it isn't valid" --- Im not sure you understand the suggestion given to you be @kevinB He suggested you use regex to not allow input of invalid characters such as "- (minus sign)"

Comment: @PaulOkeke hmm.... you mean using the pattern attribute that type="number" doesn't seem to support?

Comment: `valueAsNumber` is also NaN when empty.

Comment: There are lots of way towards this.
1. Use the pattern attribute to eliminate characters that aren't number (REGEX) pattern=/[^0-9]/g

2. Listen for "input" event :
input.addEventListener('input', function(){
                        var input = this;
                        input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9^A-Za-z]/g, "");
                    });

3: I still doubt you can't get the actual value. a simple document.getElementByName()[0].value should give you the actual value still regardless of the negative sign

Comment: @PaulOkeke pattern doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/078hhemL/ `input` event and looking at `value` doesn't work because `value` won't contain anything if it isn't a valid number. https://jsfiddle.net/078hhemL/1/

Comment: Please don't listen for change event... listen for "input" event

Comment: Check this ::: https://jsfiddle.net/jsh7tb57/

Comment: @PaulOkeke like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jsh7tb57/3/ put an invalid number in that input and see what happens.

Comment: can you check my jsfiddle again?https://jsfiddle.net/jsh7tb57/2/

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want the minus sign to show on it.. and im also guessing you only want real numbers. in that case i guess
https://jsfiddle.net/jsh7tb57/2/ this solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `event.target.validity.valid` or even better the `event.target.validity.badInput` property to check if the value is valid.
(*although `badInput` does not seem to be supported by IE*)

But i would use the `input` event instead of the `change` event, because if the user enters invalid input when starting at an empty `<input>` element, the `change` event will not fire since the `value` is considered empty (*due to it being invalid*)

---

Alternatively, you could use the css `:invalid` selector and use it to show a message that is hidden (*requires specific html structure*)

```
input[type="number"] ~ span.message{display:none;}
input[type="number"]:invalid ~ span.message{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input that mimics your `[type=number]` one:

```js
var numberInput = document.querySelector('input[type=number]');
var dolly = document.querySelector('input[hidden]');
numberInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.key !== 'Backspace') {
    dolly.value += event.key;
  } else {
    dolly.value = dolly.value.substr(0, dolly.value.length - 1);
  }
  console.log(dolly.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
<input hidden>
```

Obviously, you will need to do more processing for certain keys. This way you get the benefits of the `number` type and also maintain whatever crazy stuff the user puts in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about getting the value, but since you want to set a custom validation message, you can use input `setCustomValidity` property (see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Customized_error_messages)) and check if an input is valid using the `validity.valid` property. Here's my implementation.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("my-input");

myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (!myInput.validity.valid) {
    myInput.setCustomValidity("I expect a valid number, darling!");
  } else {
    myInput.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Please provide me a number</label>
  <input type="number" id="my-input" name="my-input">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```